# add x number of inputs to form based on select dropdown value

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs2

I've run into a situation that I am not sure what the best way to handle it is.

I've got a form that needs to be dynamic. Basically, how many phone numbers to add to the form situation.

Ive got dropdown_1 which has options 1 to 10.

If they select, say 5, I want 5 text inputs to appear.

Some Code:

Dropdown_1

```
<select id="answer_number" name="answer_number" required="required" class="custom-select"v-model="rubric.answer_number">
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
 <option value="7">7</option>
 <option value="8">8</option>
 <option value="9">9</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Input desired

```
<div class="form-group row" v-for="(score, index) in rubric.answer_number">
 <label for="score_text" class="col-2 col-form-label">Score text</label> 
 <div class="col-10">
  <input id="score_text" name="score_text" placeholder="Yes" type="text" required="required" class="form-control here">
 </div>
</div>
```

Data Store:

```
rubric: {
 reader_type: null,
 document_type: null,
 title: null,
 question: null,
 answer_number: null,
 score_text_0: null,
 score_text_1: null,
 score_text_2: null,
 score_text_3: null,
 score_text_4: null,
 score_text_5: null,
 score_text_6: null,
 score_text_7: null,
 score_text_8: null,
 score_text_9: null,
 score_text_10: null,
            }
```

do I need to trigger a function on the dropdown select, which builds an array to iterate over the desired input, or is there some built in way with VueJS to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add parseInt to rubric.answer_number because from select is a String, and script is:

```js
 var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Seleccionar: ',
        rubric: { answer_number: 2 }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    {{message}}
    <select id="answer_number" name="answer_number" required="required" class="custom-select" v-model="rubric.answer_number">
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    Seleccionados: {{rubric.answer_number}}
    <div class="form-group row" v-for="(score, index) in parseInt(rubric.answer_number)">
      <label for="score_text" class="col-2 col-form-label">Score text</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input id="score_text" name="score_text" placeholder="Yes" type="text" required="required" class="form-control here">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I run into error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". I've declared all the possible variables from the start, what could be the problem? I've added my variable store structure in the original question for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: You can add array scores_text into rubric : 
`code`
rubric: { answer_number: 0, scores:[] }

And add v-model to input:
`code`
<input id="score_text" v-model="rubric.scores[index]" name="score_text" placeholder="Yes" type="text" required="required" class="form-control here">

Answer (score 0):

You can stay with `v-model` on select, just add `number` modifier to make Vue to iterate over it in `v-for`. But you need to provide method to  change dynamic input value and store it as well (see `updateAnswer` method).

If you want to clear inputs on selected number changed you can watch it(see snippet) otherwise you should split `v-model` on select to `:value` and `@change` and clear the `answers` array in change handler.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rubric: {
        answer_number: 2
    },
    answers: []
  },
  methods: {
      updateAnswer(i, val) {
         Vue.set(this.answers, i, val);
      }
  },
  watch: {
     // clear array on number changed
     ['rubric.answer_number']() {
         this.answers = [];
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select id="answer_number" name="answer_number" required="required" class="custom-select"v-model.number="rubric.answer_number">
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
     <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  <div class="form-group row" v-for="(score, index) in rubric.answer_number">
   <label for="score_text" class="col-2 col-form-label">Score text</label> 
   <div class="col-10">
    <input id="score_text" :value="answers[index]" @input="updateAnswer(index, $event.target.value)" name="score_text" placeholder="Yes" type="text" required="required" class="form-control here">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```